# apt-get install and resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: apt

When I try and install a package with apt-get, I get the error message:

`E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have two package installers open at the same time.  For example, if you have the [Synaptic Package Manager](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) running and attempt to install a package using `apt-get` you will receive this message.  This is true even if Synaptic is simply open and doing nothing else.

Shutdown Synaptic and then retry the `apt-get` command.